# How to programmatically add things to JS object?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm using Shopify and have to add Qubit to a clients site.

At any given time there's a "basket" object which shows what products are in a users cart.

How do I dynamically insert objects into this json structure?

```
  "line_items": [{
      "product": {
        "id": "1234567890",
        "sku_code": "0987654321",
        "url": "product.html",
        "name": "Sparkly Shoes",
        "description": "Description about this product",
        "manufacturer": "The Shoe Co",
        "category": "Shoe",
        "subcategory": "Heels",
        "color": "n/a",
        "stock": 3,
        "size": "6",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "unit_price": 130,
        "unit_sale_price": 130,
        "voucher": "MYVOUCHER1"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "subtotal": 130,
      "total_discount": 0
    }, {
      "product": {
        "id": "1234567890",
        "sku_code": "0987654321",
        "url": "product-dress.html",
        "name": "Red Dress",
        "description": "Description about this product",
        "manufacturer": "The Dress Co",
        "category": "Dresses",
        "subcategory": "Red dresses",
        "color": "n/a",
        "stock": 3,
        "size": "6",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "unit_price": 200,
        "unit_sale_price": 150,
        "voucher": "MYVOUCHER1"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "subtotal": 200,
      "total_discount": 50
    }, {
      "product": {
        "id": "1234567890",
        "sku_code": "0987654321",
        "url": "product-swimwear.html",
        "name": "Bikini",
        "description": "Description about this product",
        "manufacturer": "The Bikini Co",
        "category": "Swimwear",
        "subcategory": "Bikini",
        "color": "n/a",
        "stock": 3,
        "size": "6",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "unit_price": 100,
        "unit_sale_price": 100,
        "voucher": "MYVOUCHER1"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "subtotal": 100,
      "total_discount": 0
    }]
  },
```

Taken from: http://tools.qubitproducts.com/uv/demosite/guide.html

It could be one product, or two products, etc... how would I dynamically iterate through the available products in the shopping cart (psuedo code is fine) and then display a few values?

---

If I were defining the above json structure how would I do it dynamically? Just put a loop in between the code? (feels dirty?)

Comment: I think you might be confusing JSON (a serialization format) with Javascript objects (runtime things you can manipulate). Can you give some example of what kind of code you are thinking about?

Comment: Are you asking how to add the product to the cart, after already getting the product data fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided is not JSON. It is a javascript object missing a `{` as missingno stated. You can use Kelly J Andrews answer to add items to the object or copy the object and add items to it to create an updated object. To get an object to JSON you can use `JSON.stringify()` like

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({"obj":{"param":"val"}});
```

or

```
var obj = {"obj":{"param":"val"}}; 
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

But in your case you already have an object. The code you provided has line breaks and is not a string so we can easily throw a `var obj =` (plus the `{` you left out) and have:

```
var obj = 
 { "line_items": 
  [{
    "product": {
      "id": "1234567890",
      "sku_code": "0987654321",
      "url": "product.html",
      "name": "Sparkly Shoes",
      "description": "Description about this product",
      "manufacturer": "The Shoe Co",
      "category": "Shoe",
      "subcategory": "Heels",
      "color": "n/a",
      "stock": 3,
      "size": "6",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "unit_price": 130,
      "unit_sale_price": 130,
      "voucher": "MYVOUCHER1"
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "subtotal": 130,
    "total_discount": 0
  }, {
    "product": {
      "id": "1234567890",
      "sku_code": "0987654321",
      "url": "product-dress.html",
      "name": "Red Dress",
      "description": "Description about this product",
      "manufacturer": "The Dress Co",
      "category": "Dresses",
      "subcategory": "Red dresses",
      "color": "n/a",
      "stock": 3,
      "size": "6",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "unit_price": 200,
      "unit_sale_price": 150,
      "voucher": "MYVOUCHER1"
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "subtotal": 200,
    "total_discount": 50
  }, {
    "product": {
      "id": "1234567890",
      "sku_code": "0987654321",
      "url": "product-swimwear.html",
      "name": "Bikini",
      "description": "Description about this product",
      "manufacturer": "The Bikini Co",
      "category": "Swimwear",
      "subcategory": "Bikini",
      "color": "n/a",
      "stock": 3,
      "size": "6",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "unit_price": 100,
      "unit_sale_price": 100,
      "voucher": "MYVOUCHER1"
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "subtotal": 100,
    "total_discount": 0
  }]
};
```

Now we can use Kelly's solution and add thing to the object:

```
var productToAdd = {
  "product": {
    "id": "123456789",
    "sku_code": "135792468"
  },
  "quantity": 3,
  "subtotal": 369,
  "total_discount": 0
};
obj["line_items"].push(productToAdd);
```

When we add all our products to the object we can `JSON.stringify()` if we need to send the object as JSON back to the server:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

If you have an actual JSON string coming in you can use JSON.parse() like

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"obj":{"param":"val"}}');
```

or

```
var json = '{"obj":{"param":"val"}}'; 
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

then add objects.

Comment: I hope this is ordered kinda right. I feel like it should be explained in a different order to avoid redundant explanations.

Comment: I was going off the actual object from the website, assuming he provided a snippet - this is solid info though.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the data - it should be fairly simple (based on the above mentioned site's data)-

```
window.universal_variable["basket"]["line_items"].push(myProductObj);
```

The`myProductObj` would be the following:

```
{
      "product": {
        "id": "1234567890",
        "sku_code": "0987654321",
        "url": "product.html",
        "name": "Sparkly Shoes",
        "description": "Description about this product",
        "manufacturer": "The Shoe Co",
        "category": "Shoe",
        "subcategory": "Heels",
        "color": "n/a",
        "stock": 3,
        "size": "6",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "unit_price": 130,
        "unit_sale_price": 130,
        "voucher": "MYVOUCHER1"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "subtotal": 130,
      "total_discount": 0
    }
```